# New firmware for WRT Belkin F5D7632-4?

Tags: router, open-source, dd-wrt, firmware, openwrt

I have an older spare ADSL-modem/router/AP/switch from Belkin (F5D7632-4).

I spent some time seeking an open source firmware ala OpenWRT or DD-WRT.

My problem is that the chipsets do not seem to be supported anywhere, which I find strange as it was a common device a few years back.

I have opened it and here is a few names which may help you identify the appropriate firmware:

- Infineon ADM6996L (Ethernet switch
  controller)
- Conexant DA4-9401-PCA
  (ARM chip)
- ISL 3886IK (AKA Intersil
  or Prism, WiFi controller)

FCC's details about the device:

https://fjallfoss.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=N&application_id=767023&fcc_id=%27K7SF5D7632-4%27

Any suggestions or feedback is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible with this model.

Comment: The reason being is the wireless chip inside the router.  Just because it was popular does not make it easier to support.  As tot he reason its not support even today, the ISL 3886IK is not in any recently released router to my knowlege.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a particularly troublesome model.

For DD-WRT, your router is on the list of [Known incompatible devices](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices).

For OpenWRT, none of the WRT models are on the Table of Hardware, [Belkin section](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start#belkin).

[Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [OpenLinksys](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openlinksys/) do not apply to Belkin.

The thread [Belkin F5D7632-4 v2000 FIRMWARE UPDATE WARNING](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/18/networking/228171/belkin-f5d7632-4-v2000-firmware-update-warning/) even cites problems
with updating this model to the latest firmware version from Belkin (and it is not the only such thread).

So I am all fresh out of ideas for any firmware update for this router.
Sorry for the negative answer.

Comment: I took a look at OpenLinksys, DD-WRT and OpenWRT. What makes it interesting is that the v4000 model I have isn't GPL'd, but the v5000 model is, I'm wondering if it's worth using that source as a starting point and going from there. Failing that, time to buy a new modem/router.

Comment: I would go for the later, unless you have several weeks/months to spare. I would choose a good router supported by DD-WRT without any mechanical manipulations.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have another router, it was just to get more out of it if possible.